# get admin/sales_order/view/order_id URL in Grid's Action Column

Tags: magento

I have created grid in new module. and it contains Action column. Action's URL is not coming as 
**admin/sales_order/view/order_id** 
it shows 
**/sales_order/view/order_id**.

Below is the code. Can anyone tell me Where did I go wrong

Mymodule name is **Mymodule_Backorders**

```
$this->addColumn('action',
    array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
    'width'     => '50px',
    'type'      => 'action',
    'getter'     => 'getId',
    'actions'   => array(
        array(
        'caption' => 'Edit',
        'url'     => array('base'=>'sales_order/view'),
        'target'=>'_blank',
        'field'   => 'id'
        )
    ),
    'filter'    => false,
    'sortable'  => false
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array value for base url has three components - module/controller/action - and you are missing the first component.

Change `array('base'=>'sales_order/view')` to `array('base'=>'adminhtml/sales_order/view'),`.
If the action that you would refer to would be in a controller inside your own module you could also use `array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),` where * gets automatically replaced with the module name to which the class, that calls the getUrl function, belongs to.